# Eclipse inserting data into SQLite Database, no such table

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse, sqlite

I'm trying to insert data into the database but it tells me there's no such table. I also have another sqlite database inside the application, i'm not sure if that affects this one, but I don't think so. It uses the same database name, but a different table name. If you think it does affect it, tell me and I'll post up the code for that too. 
The logcat gives me these messages:

```
(1) no such table: notes
Error inserting title=Bleh desc=bleh
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: notes (code 1): , while         compiling: INSERT INTO notes(title,desc) VALUES (?,?)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
at com.example.stepsaway.NoteActivity.addEntry(NoteActivity.java:102)
at com.example.stepsaway.NoteActivity.onClick(NoteActivity.java:75)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The Activity java is:

```
public class NoteActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button buttonLeaveNote; 

private EditText mTitle;
private EditText mDesc;

protected NoteDBHelper noteDB = new NoteDBHelper(NoteActivity.this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);

    buttonLeaveNote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLeaveNote);
    buttonLeaveNote.setOnClickListener(this);

    mTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etitle);
    mDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edesc);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.note, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.buttonLeaveNote:

           String title = mTitle.getText().toString();
           String desc = mDesc.getText().toString();


           boolean invalid = false;

           if(title.equals(""))
           {
            invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else
               if(desc.equals(""))
               {
                  invalid = true;
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               } 

               else

                   if(invalid == false)
                   {
                       addEntry(title, desc);
                       Intent i_note = new Intent(NoteActivity.this, JustWanderingActivity.class);
                       startActivity(i_note);
                       //finish();
                      }

                      break;
                      }
                    }

public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    noteDB.close();
}

private void addEntry(String title, String desc) 
 {
    SQLiteDatabase notedb = noteDB.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put("title", title);
      values.put("desc", desc);
      //values.put("lati", lati);
      //values.put("lng", lng);
      try
      {
       long newRowId;
       newRowId = notedb.insert(NoteDBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Note successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      catch(Exception e)
      {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } 
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
}
```

And the Database java is:

```
public class NoteDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 

{
 private SQLiteDatabase notedb;

public static final String NOTE_ID = "_nid";
public static final String NOTE_TITLE = "title";
public static final String NOTE_DESC = "desc";
public static final String NOTE_LAT = "lati";
public static final String NOTE_LONG = "lng";


NoteDBHelper noteDB = null;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "stepsaway.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "notes";


private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
        "_nid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "title TEXT NOT NULL, desc LONGTEXT NOT NULL);";

public NoteDBHelper(Context context) {

super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
System.out.println("In constructor");
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase notedb) {

try{

notedb.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE);


}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase notedb, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




public Cursor rawQuery(String string, String[] strings) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}




public void open() {

getWritableDatabase(); 
}


public Cursor getDetails(String text) throws SQLException 
{

Cursor mCursor =
        notedb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, 
          new String[]{NOTE_ID, NOTE_TITLE, NOTE_DESC}, 
          NOTE_TITLE + "=" + text, 
          null, null, null, null, null);
if (mCursor != null) 
{
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
return mCursor;


}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Edit: Looks like the problem is creating a second table within the same database name. It won't let me create a second one. The first time creating the DB works fine, but it gives the SQLite Exception with no such table when trying to create another table. Is there some code I need to alter or add to create a second table? Because all i did was create another sqlite database java with the same DATABASE_NAME, but a different DATABASE_TABLE_NAME.

Comment: did you check whether table created or not

Comment: If you have created the DB before and adding a table afterwards this can cause the problem. Tables are created for the first time DB created. So uninstall or clean the data in the app from device and run it again.

Comment: @osayilgan oh wow, thanks! this solved the problem (:
Edit: I have a new problem though. I see the problem is creating a second table in the same database. It doesn't work for some reason. I have one table to register users, and the other table is the one posted here, to create notes.

Comment: @user2905867 I don't think I understand the issue clearly. But if you want to create a table you need to implement it in onCreate of SQLiteOpenHelper class. Run the DB creating string there.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is when you create `nodeDB` object, the activity is still not available. Therefore you will failed creating the table.

You can try moving how you initialise the noteDB into inside `onCreate()`:

```
protected NoteDBHelper noteDB;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);

    noteDB = new NoteDBHelper(NoteActivity.this);


    buttonLeaveNote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLeaveNote);
    buttonLeaveNote.setOnClickListener(this);

    mTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etitle);
    mDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edesc);
}
```

Comment: This. Many people do this. The context will not be available till the call to `super.onCreate()` is complete.

Comment: Tried this and still get the same exception with no such table

Comment: This is good and valid advice, though if this was the OP's problem, it would result in NPE usually in `getBaseContext()`. Why it doesn't NPE in this case is that `SQLiteOpenHelper` doesn't actually *use* the `Context` in constructor, it just stores it for later use (when e.g. `getWritableDatabase()` is invoked).

Answer (score 1):

Your `onUpgrade()` is empty and database schema version is 2. My guess is that your initial version of the database didn't have the `notes` table and when it was later added, the empty upgrade code couldn't add it. But `SQLiteOpenHelper` is satisfied as it is now running version 2 of the database.

To fix it once, clean your app data. E.g. in settings app, go to manage apps -> downloaded -> select your app and click on the "Clear application data" button. Or just uninstall and reinstall the app. This approach is good enough during development.

To fix it for released versions, implement `onUpgrade()` so that is updates the database schema and does any necessary data migration. If you're not concerned about data loss, you can just call `DROP TABLE` on the old tables and then call `onCreate()` to recreate the tables.

---

To your follow-up question regarding multiple tables: Just use the same helper class to manage the database. One helper per database file. Create all tables in `onCreate()` and do any required migrations in `onUpgrade()`.

Comment: your answer is make sense and valid

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to First issue : as I explained in my comment >

- If you have created the DB before and adding a table afterwards this can cause the problem. Tables are created for the first time DB created. So uninstall or clean the data in the app from device and run it again.

For the Second Issue :

- If you want to Create a table, do the same that you are already doing for the table you have.

  @Override

  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase notedb) {

  try{

  ```
   notedb.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE);

   notedb.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE_STRING_2);
  ```

  }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

}